# Serial construction of a string in for-loop with mempcpy leads to endless recursion

Tags: c, linux, recursion, memcpy

The following code snipped is a simplification of code I'm currently working on. It is designed to construct an output string, constructed via a concatenation of strings.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <argp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *english[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
                    "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    char *l_english = malloc(5*sizeof(char)*10+10+1); 
    char *ptr_eng = l_english;   
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        ptr_eng = mempcpy(ptr_eng,english[i],strlen(english[i]));
        printf("Iteration %d\n",i);
    }
    free(l_english);
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with gcc 4.8.3 under Gentoo Linux. When I run the above program, it does not halt but consumes 100% of a CPU core. Looking at it with gdb, it turns out that the `mempcpy` goes into endless recursion.

Now on to the things I've already tried:

1. Unrolling the for-loop. This works perfectly fine if I simply write out the instructions instead of using the for-loop.
2. Setting a constant size to copy for mempcpy. Yet again, no endless recursion.
3. Using `memcpy` and not changing the pointer ´ptr_eng´ inside the loop: Again, no endless recursion.
4. In relation to 3., using `memcpy` and setting `eng_ptr = eng_ptr+strlen(english[i])`. Again, the endless recursion happened.

Sadly, when I Google for `memcpy` and for-loops, I only find discussions about performance. I am quite the newbie where C is concerned, and I would be grateful for any pointer you can provide.

**EDIT**

Here is a link to the relevant gdb output http://pastebin.com/nBZhqnsw; this goes on until a segfault occurs.

**EDIT 2**

To clear things up: The above code is only a simplified example of a program I am currently working on. The formula for the size in the `malloc` call was actually only a throwaway replacement for a number of variables used to compute the actual amount of memory needed in the real program. The only important thing for this example is that it is enough memory to hold the ten words from the `english` variable.

The expected result is for l_english to be a pointer to the beginning of a chunk of memory holding "zeroonetwothreefourfivesixseveneightnine". Like I said, it is only a simplification for the sake of Stack Overflow.

Comment: The `memcpy` function doesn't use recursion. And the program as shown in your question [work fine](http://ideone.com/Qh34la) (but not the way you want it to work). If you get `memcpy` to recurse, you probably overwrite the stack in some way.

Comment: @Michael Meier What exactly function are you using: memcpy or mempcpy?!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg First, thanks for pointing out ideone.com. I've linked to an example gdb output in the question. That looks like recursion to me. I am rather surprised to see the program working (actually, exactly as intended) in your link. Could it be that my compiler does something weird?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I intend to use memPcpy, but I also tested memcpy and increasing the ptr_eng by hand, where the same error occured.

Comment: I swapped out the non-portable `mempcpy()` for `memcpy(ptr_eng,english[i],strlen(english[i])); ptr_eng += strlen(english[i]);` and it works fine on my system (Clang, OS X).

Comment: @JohnZwinck Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: You might want to copy the string null termination for your program to be useful. In general, calling strlen() from inside memcpy() doesn't make much sense. You might as well use strcpy() in that case.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yeah, I tried that one too, see No 4. in my question, and it produced the same behavior, an endless loop of memcpy calls. I simply don't understand why it seems to work for everyone but me. Perhaps someone might be willing to try it with gcc on a Linux system?

Comment: @Ludin No, that is exactly what I don't want to do, and why I use memcpy/mempcpy instead of strcpy: In the end, I want a string concatenation of all the values in english. If I'm not mistaken, strcpy puts a terminator at the end of each string, which would make printf stop too early, namely at the \0 after "zero", if I wanted to print l_english.

Comment: make sure you add a null terminator at the end of `l_english`... that doesn't have any bearing on your problem though.

Comment: Note that `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { strcpy(ptr_eng, english[i]); ptr_eng += strlen(english[i]); }` would leave you with a single null terminated string containing all the words copied so far.  I'd always try to include the 'output so far' in the diagnostic printing.  Indeed, I used `calloc(1, 5*sizeof(char)*10+10+1)` to set the memory to zeroes and then used `printf("Iteration %d (%s)\n", i, l_english);` to print. However, since I don't see the bug in the first place, that isn't a lot of help (but it does confirm that the code is doing what it is supposed to do — for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem: I compiled my code with GCC under Linux with --std=c99. At the link provided by @Joachim Pileborg in his comment to my question, I saw the option --std=gnu99.

Out of pure despair I tried it...and the program ran smoothly. The compiler obviously did something funny there.

Thanks to you all for your comments.

Comment: One way of further qualifying this behaviour would be to print out `ptr_eng` in the body of the loop, so you can see whether the pointer goes haywire or not.  The GDB trace you show shows the same value 0x604010 for the destination pointer every time after the first iteration, though as it also shows the same source address I might be misinterpreting the data.  Also, you mention 'recursion', but you don't show any stack trace showing that there is recursion in progress.  At the moment, it smacks of a 'compiler bug'. (FWIW: I can't reproduce on Ubuntu 14.04 with GCC 4.8.2.)

Comment: I won't even say it was a compiler bug as much as it was a user error on my side. I had defined ´_GNU_SOURCE´. I think doing that and on the other hand not compiling with --std=gnu99 is a simple error on my side, not on the compiler's.

Comment: Not an error as I understand it.  Specifying `-std=c99` means that the GNU source features were disabled by default; by explicitly enabling the GNU source features with `#define _GNU_SOURCE`, you are working with perfectly correct code (from my viewpoint).  I routinely compile with `-std=c11` and enable the POSIX extensions (and X/Open extensions) with `#define _XOPEN_VERSION 700` or equivalent, and when I need `_GNU_SOURCE`, then I add that to the code (and likewise with `_BSD_SOURCE` when that's needed).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it doesn't work, so I'll just advise you to keep the program simple and everything will work out well:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char* english[] = 
    {
      "zero", 
      "one", 
      "two", 
      "three", 
      "four", 
      "five",
      "six", 
      "seven", 
      "eight", 
      "nine"
    };

    char *l_english = malloc(5*sizeof(char)*10+1); // 5 chars times 10 plus nul
    char *ptr_eng = l_english;   
    for(size_t i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        const char* ptr_ch = english[i];

        while(*ptr_ch != '\0')
        {
            *ptr_eng = *ptr_ch;
            ptr_eng++;
            ptr_ch++;
        }

        printf("Iteration %d\n",i);
    }
    *ptr_eng = '\0';   

    puts(l_english);

    free(l_english);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Iteration 0
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
Iteration 4
Iteration 5
Iteration 6
Iteration 7
Iteration 8
Iteration 9
zeroonetwothreefourfivesixseveneightnine
```

In addition, the while loop above is more efficient than memcpy + strlen.

Comment: Found my problem, it was with the compiler flags rather than the code itself. Kudos for showing that simple way of copying strings.